# Part of footnote appears in italics, and some italic characters are subscripts. Why?

Tags: fonts, formatting

I know I should provide a minimum working example, but that would be very complex for me. So perhaps a kind reader could point me to a possible source of this puzzling corruption. I searched here and elsewhere but couldn't find anything relevant. (Perhaps my search skills need a reboot?)

My document has has a footnote generated by the following code excerpt —

```
... \footnote{As of 2012, the smallest
non-Hispanic white percentages were in Hawaii (22.8\%), D.C. (35.3\%),
California (35.2\%), New Mexico (39.7\%), Texas (44.3\%), and then Nevada (52.7\%). 
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_non-Hispanic_white_population}
```

That code produces odd anomalies in the pdf when compiled (XeLaTeX), with the underscore character gone and the following letter rendered as a subscript, and the hyphen magically becoming a dash:

[image: footnote with unexplained oddities]

The preamble looks like this —

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[protrusion=false,expansion]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec} % allow use of system fonts
\usepackage[fontsize=10pt,baseline=12pt]{grid} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{} 
\setmainfont{Alegreya}%{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=0.5in,left=2.75cm,right=1.75cm,includehead,head=12pt,headsep=12pt,includefoot,foot=0.5in,footskip=0.9602in,twoside]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.8em}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: you would have had an error message about math mode. Never use a pdf file after any error. You need `\_` to get a text underscore character.

Comment: Load `\usepackage{hyperref}` or `\usepackage{url}` and then use `\url` to mark up URLs: `\footnote{As of 2012, the smallest
non-Hispanic white percentages were in Hawaii (22.8\%), D.C. (35.3\%),
California (35.2\%), New Mexico (39.7\%), Texas (44.3\%), and then Nevada (52.7\%). 
Source: \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_non-Hispanic_white_population}}` (There should have been an error message about `! Missing $ inserted.` at the `_`: Never ignore error messages! If you have an issue look at the error messages first.)

Comment: Unrelated, but youu are using fontspec so must be using luatex or xelatex so never use inputenc so remove `\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}`

Comment: With XeLaTeX you also do not want to load `fontenc`, so remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: Slightly related: do you see how Mico was able to give a 10 line minimal working example after all?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies (and resolution of this perplexing issue). I don't have occasion to use LaTeX for math, though I do know enough to escape control characters like the backslash and dollar sign. I had no idea before today that math mode could be triggered by an underscore. I did get an error message about inserting a missing dollar sign, which puzzled me, especially as I didn't see any inserted dollar sign. I'm sufficiently inexperienced to often find myself befuddled by cryptic or overly terse error messages. But I learned something(s) new today, and I thank you all.

Comment: @Artmancc - The expression "math mode could be triggered by an underscore" isn't quite right. The issue is not that math mode is triggered by an underscore character; instead, it is that unescaped underscore characters should only ever occur while TeX is *already in math mode*. If TeX comes across `_` while not in math mode, it issues an error message (which you ingored at your own peril) and switches to math mode. Clearly, though, that's *not* the right working assumption when dealing with URL strings. Hence the recommenation in my answer, to encase URL strings in `\url` directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you load the `xurl` package and encase the URL string in a `\url` wrapper. Observe that `xurl` allows URL strings to be line-broken at any place.

And, since you employ the `fontspec` package, you should *not* load the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages. Just make sure that the input file is UTF8-encoded, as that's the one and only input encoding recognized by both XeTeX and LuaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Alegreya}
\usepackage{xurl}
\setlength\textheight{2.5cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\dots~various facts.\footnote{As of 2012, the smallest non-Hispanic white percentages were in Hawaii (22.8\%), D.C. (35.3\%), California (35.2\%), New Mexico (39.7\%), Texas (44.3\%), and Nevada (52.7\%). 
Source: \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_non-Hispanic_white_population}}
\end{document}
```